# TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con el siguiente código en Python

```
def reproduccion(self, poblacion, seleccionados):

    point = 0
    father = []

    for i in range(len(poblacion)):
        point = np.random.randint(1, len(self.target) - 1)
        father = random.sample(seleccionados, 2)

        poblacion[i][:point] = father[0][:point]
        poblacion[i][point:] = father[1][point:]
    
    return poblacion
```

Pero noto que al poner el mouse encima de father(ya que me aparece subrayado de que tiene un error) me sale:

> Value 'father[0]' is unsubscriptable

Al correr el Código el error es:

> TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

¿cuál podría ser el error?

Comment: Debes poner una muestra (no toda la lista de valores) de `población`, `seleccionados`, `self.target` y cual es la salida deseada.

Answer (score 0):

me podrias decir que forma tienen los elementos 'poblacion', 'seleccionados' y 'target' con un ejemplo. Es decir, ej: poblacion=[(1, 2, 3),[1,3]].
Si me decis eso el problema es sencillo de resolver.

Comment: Bienvenido Martín c: A pesar de que lo que dices contribuye, esta es la sección de respuestas, y esta no es una respuesta. Cuando tengas suficiente reputacion (50) podrás comentar en cualquier publicación. Pero gracias igual por tu intento de ayudar c: